# what is the need of docker or docker EE if I can run my container directly by installing docker engine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

what is the need of docker CE or docker EE if I can run my container directly by installing docker engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker changed the name of Docker Engine to Docker CE.

Plenty of companies want enterprise support and features which is what you'd get with Docker EE.  Docker EE also comes with a price tag whereas Docker CE does not.  You can build/install the Docker engine, but you don't get access to Docker's enterprise features.

Docker's documentation is quite good and you should be able to find additional information there.

The "need" depends on what your requirements are. You don't even need Docker to run a container.